# Question about enumerability

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If a set is enumerable, is the following true:

Edit: My definition of enumerable is: There is a one-to-one correspondence between the set and the natural numbers.

$A$ is enumerable $\iff \exists$ an injection $\sigma: A\to \mathbb{N} \iff A$ is countable

I am not sure if this is true if $A$ is not infinite. Can finite sets me enumerable?

Thank you

Comment: How do you define “enumerable”?

Comment: Enumerability doesn't seem to be defined in my lecture notes. So I would define enumerability as the above equivalence.

Comment: So, your question is “$A$ is enumerable $\iff A$ is enumerable?” Am I right?

Comment: I see what you mean. I would define a set to be enumerable if there is a one-to-one correspondence with the natural numbers. In which case I think my eqivalence is correct.

Comment: What's an one-to-one correspondence between a set $A$ and the natural numbers? Isn't that exactly the existence of an injection from $A$ into $\Bbb N$?

Comment: I think so, yes. Presumably this means $A$ must be infinite.

Comment: See [Countable set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set): "In mathematics, a set is countable if it has the same cardinality (the number of elements of the set) as some subset of the set of natural numbers. Equivalently, a set S is countable if there exists an injective function... A countable set is either a *finite* set or a *countably infinite* set."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe check the wikipedia page for "Countable Sets". Usually "enumerable" refers to countable (in the not infinite sense).

[image]

Note that if there is an injection (that is not a surjection) from a set $A$ to $\mathbb{N}$, this is the same as saying there is a bijection between $A$ and a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, in this case $A$ has at most the cardilanity of the naturals. If this map is also a surjection, then $A$ has the same cardinality as the natural numbers.

The problem in your definition is that it doesn't specify if the map $\sigma$ is strictly an injection or if it can be bijective.

Comment: This was helpful, thank you

Comment: $\mathbb{N} \setminus \{1\}$ is also a subset of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: As Hermis14 suggests, there are infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, so having an injection from $A$ to $\mathbb{N}$ that is not a surjection does not necessarily mean that $A$ is finite.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I edited the answer, maybe it's better now?